# Lua Function Scope

Tags: function, scope, lua, love2d

So I've got a hopefully easy question, but I don't understand why my code isn't doing what I want it to.

```
function Sound:load()
 trackToPlay = musicDownbeat

 trackToPlay:play()
end

function Sound:changeMusic()
 if trackToPlay == musicUpbeat then
      trackToPlay:stop()
      trackToPlay = musicDownbeat
      trackToPlay:play()
 end
 if trackToPlay == musicDownbeat then
      trackToPlay:stop()
      trackToPlay = musicUpbeat
      trackToPlay:play()
 end
end
```

So I've got two Source tracks that can be alternated between, musicUpbeat and musicDownbeat, and at this point in the code (I have stripped down Sound:load() to make it as clear as possible), every time changeMusic() is called, trackToPlay is always musicDownbeat, meaning that every time changeMusic() is called, the music stops and is changed to musicUpbeat.

Sound:load() is only called once, right? So why are my trackToPlay changes not being saved?

Comment: "Sound:load() is only called once, right?" I don't know; it's your function, right? How often do you call it? Or is this a specialized Lua environment?

Comment: I'm also using the Love2D framework, sorry, I should have included that, though I don't know if that would have anything to do with the problem. The function is, for the moment, being called each time I press the "f" key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the function `changeMusic`. You need to use `elseif` instead of two `if` statements. Your code should look like this:

```
function Sound:changeMusic()
 if trackToPlay == musicUpbeat then
      trackToPlay:stop()
      trackToPlay = musicDownbeat
      trackToPlay:play()
 elseif trackToPlay == musicDownbeat then
      trackToPlay:stop()
      trackToPlay = musicUpbeat
      trackToPlay:play()
 end
end
```

The way you have written it in your original code, if `trackToPlay` is `musicUpbeat` (it will be after `changeMusic` is called the first time), it will be changed into `musicDownbeat` by the first statement, and then immediately changed into `musicUpbeat` by the second `if` statement.